# Set custom property in Tomcat7

Tags: java, windows, tomcat7, shibboleth

We are running our application using Tomcat-7 in Windows environment. We are using Shibboleth IDP for our application, due to this we need to set system property at the container level to identify one new property called "idp.home". So we found that the property can be set in "catalina.properties". We set it and it was running successfully by using "idp.home" property but the problem is that if we use the same compiled war file in another machine, the property "idp.home" is not working.

## cataline.properties

idp.home=../../IdP

## Structure:

Build --> IdP
      --> tomcat-->conf-->catalina.properties

Queries:
1) Is custom property "idp.home" cached in tomcat some where?
2) do we need to set "idp.home" property in any file along with the "catalina.properties"  in tomcat.

3) Is there any other way to inform tomcat about "idp.home"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want that property for tomcat or your application?

Answer (score 0):

1. We can pass system properties with the -D parameter as VM arguments to   tomcat, for example "-Dmy.prop.name=value" 
   or
2. Place system properties in a property file and specify the path of the property file in VM arguments, for example -Dcom.propertyfiles="path of the property File"